# regex for email addresses to extract first name

Tags: regex

I have email addresses in the following format:

```
hello.world@foo.com
hello_world@bar.com
```

I'd like to return a match on the word "hello" in both instances.

I tried something like this:

```
.+?(?=\.|\_)
```

but this doesn't appear to be returning the right results. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Use `/^[^_.]+/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you guys are rock stars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to match 1 or more chars other than `.` and `_` from the string start:

```
^[^_.]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8P4lhw/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[^_.]+` - one or more (due to `+` quantifier) chars other than (as `[^...]` is a negated character class) `_` and `.` chars (inside a character class, `.` matches a literal `.`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z]+
```

This will match 1 or more alphabets at the start of your input. So it will match `hello` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you try [^._]* it should get you where you want to go.

edit- didn't see the previous response while I was typing mine. Glad you found the answer.